# project.Documects всегда пустой Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

```
string solutionPath = @"C:\...\...\ConsoleApp8.sln";
MSBuildWorkspace msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
foreach (Project project in solution.Projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(project.Name);
    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(project.Documents);
    }
}
```

при запуске проекта document всегда пустой

Answer (score 0):

Похожая проблема описана здесь: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25370

Если добавить в код вывод диагностических сообщений MSBuild:

```
var diagnostics = msWorkspace.Diagnostics;
foreach (var diagnostic in diagnostics)
{
     Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.Message);
}
```

Он покажет примерно следующее:

> Сбой Msbuild при обработке файла "..." с сообщением: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Type information for Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper was present in the whitelist cache as Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper, Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a but the type could not be loaded. unexpectedly null

Установка NuGet-пакета [Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core/15.9.20) должна решить проблему. Ошибки MSBuild при этом полностью не исчезают, однако, список документов начинает выводится:

```
foreach (Project project in solution.Projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(project.Name);                
    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("- " + document.Name);
    }
}

/* Результат:

ConsoleApp1
- Program.cs
- AssemblyInfo.cs
- .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.cs
*/
```